# Android activity backstack

Tags: android, android-manifest, onactivityresult, back-stack

I have `ScanActivity` that is marked in android manifest `noHistory=true`

```
<activity
     android:name=".ScanActivity"
     android:noHistory="true"/>
```

The priblem is that from `ScanActivity` I want to call `ProductActivity` here what I do

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (scanResult != null) {
            String result = scanResult.getContents();
            if(result != null && result.length() > 0){
                Intent productIntent = new Intent(this, ProductActivity.class);
                productIntent.putExtra("barcode", result);
                startActivity(productIntent);
            }
        }
    }
```

But because I add `noHistory=true` to scan activity onActivityResult is never called. If i set `noHistory=false` everything working. Where is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation:

> A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it. In this case, onActivityResult() is never called if you start another activity for a result from this activity.